# Open iFrame doc hyperlinks in new window instead of within iFrame window

Tags: html, iframe, html-table

This is a size chart document embedded using iFrame. The document was created with Google Sheets. Each size has a hyperlink. Clicking on the links opens the specific URL for each size. However, the URLs only open within the iFrame window and I would like them to open on the full page.

https://www.wildeones.com/ring-size-chart/

This is the code I used:

```
<iframe src="https://www.wildeones.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Ring-Size-Chart.pdf" width="100%" height="550px">﻿</iframe>
```

Thanks,

Jerome

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your problem. The links appear to open in the main browser window on firefox 104.0, chrome 104, Edge 104 and Opera 90 on Windows 10. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Hi Adam. Thanks for your comment. You're right, I just realised the issue occurs only in Safari. Can anything be done about it?

Comment: Also, the links won't open at all on mobile. I've tried Safari and FireFox.